# If $δ$ and $δ'$ both divide $α$ and $β$, and that every $γ$ which divides $α$ and $β$ also divides $δ$ and $δ'$, then $δ$ and $δ'$ are associates

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Verify that if quadratic integers $δ$ and $δ'$ both divide $α$ and $β$, and that every $γ$ which divides $α$ and $β$ also divides $δ$ and $δ'$, then $δ$ and $δ'$ are associates.

I am really confused on what a solution for this problem would be and the steps to even start getting there. How can I prove the above statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are allowed to choose $\gamma=\delta^\prime$, since $\delta^\prime\vert \alpha$ and $ \delta^\prime\vert\beta$ by assumption: Hence $\delta^\prime\vert\delta$; in the same way (e.g. choosing $\gamma=\delta$) one gets $\delta\vert\delta^\prime$ and sees that $\delta$,$\delta^\prime$ are associates.

Comment: Is it truly that simple? If so, thank you so much! You explanation seems clear to me.

Comment: I hope so. The key observation is to note that you are trying to prove a quadratic integer variant of the uniqueness of the greatest common divisor. Since not every ring of quadratic integers is an UFD, you have to work around the use of the factorization in the usual proof.

Comment: Ah. I will make sure to remember and utilize that.